# Problem on studying $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{\log{n}}}{\sqrt{n!}}\frac{\tan{n}}{|\tan{n}|+n}$, comparison criterion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

To study the convergence of the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^{\log{n}}}{\sqrt{n!}}\frac{\tan{n}}{|\tan{n}|+n}$ I have thought that:
$$\frac{n^{\log{n}}}{\sqrt{n!}}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\,\, \forall n\geq 1$$
So:
$$a_n=\frac{n^{\log{n}}}{\sqrt{n!}}\frac{\tan{n}}{|\tan{n}|+n}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \frac{\tan{n}}{|\tan{n}|+n}=b_n$$
Moreover $\frac{\tan{n}}{|\tan{n}|+n}\sim \frac{\tan{n}}{n}\implies b_n\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\frac{\tan{n}}{n}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}$.
Now $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}$ converges but I can't say that also the original series converges...
Can you help me?

**EDIT(as suggested by Marty cohen)**
$$\frac{|\tan{n}|}{||\tan{n}|+n|}<1\iff |\tan{n}|<||\tan{n}|+n|$$
Then since $n\geq 1$ then $\tan{n}>n$, so,

1. if $\tan{n}>0$ then:
   $\tan{n}<\tan{n}+n$ true.
2. if $\tan{n}<0$ then:
   $-\tan{n}<-\tan{n}+n$ true.
3. if $\tan{n}=0$ then:
   $0<0+n$ true.

Comment: Please spell out your asymptotic estimate for $b_n.$

Comment: How is for example $\tan(3)$ defined?

Comment: @Meowdog I'd say tan of 3 radians??

Comment: Well, ok, so you define it as $\sin(x)/ \cos(x)$ wherever $\cos$ does not vanish?

Comment: @coffeemath I have done this in the last but one line...what do you mean?

Comment: Whether the log is ln or log base ten, $2^{\log(2)}>2.$

Comment: $\sqrt{n!}$ is really dominant here and makes the whole thing convergent, just majorate roughly. Note the behaviour of $\tan n$ is problematic (in particular you cannot say it is $o(n)$ as you did, but since we have it on denominator also just say the whole second blob $<1$).

Comment: @pawel "Now $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}$ diverges" No it doesn't.

Comment: @Gary Well it is a typo, indeed if it was I had done :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at
$\dfrac{n^{\log{n}}}{\sqrt{n!}}\dfrac{\tan{n}}{|\tan{n}|+n}
$,
using the n-th root test,

$\begin{array}\\
\left(\dfrac{n^{\log{n}}}{\sqrt{n!}}\right)^{1/n}
&=\dfrac{n^{\log{n}/n}}{n!^{1/(2n)}}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{\log^2{n}/n}}{n!^{1/(2n)}}\\
&\approx\dfrac{e^{\log^2{n}/n}}{(n/e)^{1/2}}\\
&\to\dfrac{e^{1/2}}{n^{1/2}}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

and
$|\dfrac{\tan{n}}{|\tan{n}|+n}|
\lt 1
$

so the sum converges.

This holds true
when
$\sqrt{n!}$
is replaced by
$(n!)^a$
for any $a>0$
since
$\log(n)/n^b \to 0$
for any $b > 0$.

Comment: the text is really small, it could use dfrac instead of frac.

Comment: @martycohen So first of all you ha considered bounding the absolute value with one and then you have used the n-th root test?

Comment: Changed frac to dfrac

Comment: Regarding how I did it, I saw immediately that the term involving tan was less than one, so I just had to use $n!^{1/n}\approx n/e$.

Comment: @martycohen how do you have obtained this asymptotic estimation?

Comment: @martycohen moreover I have edited my question with the steps to bound the term with tan, can you check if I am right?

Comment: can you help me please to understand you answer???